# how to ask or post in fuelphp forum?

Tags: fuelphp

How to post a question in fuelphp forum? I already created an account but still can't see any "post a post" or "ask a question" on their site. Also, commenting is not allowed.

Comment: There are a lot of useless questions about FuelPHP on Stack Overflow. I like how you're trying to use the forums on questions not belonging here. You can also try the IRC channel, which almost instantaneously gives your answers. If you're OK with IRC, visit #fuelphp on freenode.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [⇒ New Question or Discussion](http://fuelphp.com/forums/post/discussion) button on the sidebar after logging in.

If you don't see it, it may be because of your membership requires manual confirmation, but I'm not sure I couldn't post before it, when I created my account. So, if you can't see this button, just be patient until your account is confirmed.

Comment: Well thank you, that's also what I'm thinking. Maybe they need to confirm my account first. I already tried clicking "New Question or Discussion" but page result has "Permission Problem
You don't have permission to do that.". Pretty bad for fuelphp, developer will need to wait for a while or I don't know. Thanks